# Google App Scripts - Auto Sending Emails (specific issue delete row and appendRowL)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I'm trying to use Google App Scripts to send HTML emails for me that I wrote. My code works to the point where I can get the e-mails to send however as you'll see in my code I have 4 different templates that I want to send . . As you'll see I have some code to change the template by 1 to find the right template and dateMath to increase the date for the next e-mail to send.

The issue that I'm running across right now is with deleteRow and appendRow. I have 2 users that I'm trying to e-mail and when I run the code deleteRow and appendRow replaces one of the users with the other. It'll make more sense with my screen shots. Any insight here? 
[Before Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28DeD.png)

[After Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg1O8.png)

```js
function sendEmails(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "MDT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  for(var i = 1; i<data.length; i++){
    
    if(data[i][3] !== ""){ //skip if is empty
     
      if(isValidDate(data[i][3])){ //skip if isn't a valid date
        
        var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(data[i][3], "MDT", "dd/MM/yyyy"); 

        if(formattedDate == today){ //send email if checkin date is today
          
          if(data[i][4] == 1) {  
           var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Template1');
          } else if(data[i][4] == 2){
            var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Template2');
          } else if(data[i][4] == 3){
            var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Template3');
          } else {
            var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Template4');
          }                                                                                                      
          var email = data[i][2];
          var firstName = data[i][0];
          var lastName = data[i][1];
          template.firstName = firstName;

          var subject = "Your Next Steps ";
        
          var bcc = "spencer@kwwestfield.com";
  
          var message = template.evaluate();
        
          GmailApp.sendEmail(email,
           subject,
           message.getContent(), {
             htmlBody: message.getContent(),
             bcc: bcc
          });
          
          //change the template
          //delete the row
          sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
          //add the row again
          var newTemplate = data[i][4] + 1;
          var newSend = dateMath(data[i][3], 8);
          sheet.appendRow([firstName, lastName, email, newSend, newTemplate]);
          
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Does math on dates
 * Triggered from functions
 * Input: date = the orginal date, d = +- number of days
 * Output: a new date
 */
function dateMath(date,d){
  var result = new Date(date.getTime()+d*(24*3600*1000));
  return result
}                  


/**
 * Figures out if is a data
 * Triggered from functions
 * Input: d: any
 * Output: boolean
 */
function isValidDate(d) {
  if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(d) !== "[object Date]" ){
    return false;
  } else {
    return true; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're deleting a row, the `i` value no longer corresponds to the same range. For example, you have an array with 5 elements:

```
[A, B, C, D, E]
```

If you delete element `0`, you'll get

```
[B, C, D, E]
```

Now you increment your iterator so `i++; // i = 1` and so the next *value* that you'll operate on is not "B", but instead "C".

You can try yourself by running this

```
function test() {
  var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
  for (var i=0; i<letters.length; i++) {
    Logger.log("i : " + i + " || Letter: " + letters[i]);
    letters.shift();
  }
}
```

To fix your code, add a `row` variable that is independent of your array iterator `i`.

```
function sendEmails(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "MDT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  var row = 2; // Starting at row 2
  for(var i = 1; i<data.length; i++){

    if(data[i][3] !== ""){ //skip if is empty

      if(isValidDate(data[i][3])){ //skip if isn't a valid date

        var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(data[i][3], "MDT", "dd/MM/yyyy"); 

        if(formattedDate == today){ //send email if checkin date is today

          if(data[i][4] == 1) {  
           var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Template1');
          } else if(data[i][4] == 2){
            var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Template2');
          } else if(data[i][4] == 3){
            var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Template3');
          } else {
            var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Template4');
          }                                                                                                      
          var email = data[i][2];
          var firstName = data[i][0];
          var lastName = data[i][1];
          template.firstName = firstName;

          var subject = "Your Next Steps ";

          var bcc = "spencer@kwwestfield.com";

          var message = template.evaluate();

          GmailApp.sendEmail(email,
           subject,
           message.getContent(), {
             htmlBody: message.getContent(),
             bcc: bcc
          });

          //change the template
          //delete the row
          sheet.deleteRow(row);
          row--; // Deleted a row
          //add the row again
          var newTemplate = data[i][4] + 1;
          var newSend = dateMath(data[i][3], 8);
          sheet.appendRow([firstName, lastName, email, newSend, newTemplate]);

        }
      } 
    }
    row++; // Go to the next row
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Total novice coder here, I appreciate your input and helping me find the solution! It works great now!